# manually defined method works, but define_method does not, no error given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The below works when I define my method manually, but when I use some meta-programming to define my method the code is not working.  What is wrong with my code?

### In my model

#### Works

```
  def amount=(value)
    value = value.gsub(/[\,]/,'') if value.is_a?(String) 
    write_attribute(:aum, value)
  end
```

#### Works 2

```
[:amount].each do |field|
  define_method("#{field.to_s}=".intern) do |value|
    value = value.gsub(/[\,]/,'') if value.is_a?(String) # remove , 
    write_attribute(field.intern, value)
  end
end
```

#### Does not work

```
 stripe_commas_from(:amount)

 def self.stripe_commas_from(*fields)
  fields.each do |field|
    define_method "#{field.to_s}=".intern do |value|
      value = value.gsub(/[\,]/,'') if value.is_a?(String) # remove , 
      write_attribute(field.intern, value)
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: That's the thing, no error, it just does create the methods

Comment: what happens when you do `YourClass.new.amount = 1`

Comment: if I do YourClass.new.amount = '1,000', I also get 1 instead of 1000, so my define method does not seem to work.

Comment: in rails console do `i = YourClass.new; i.amount = '1,000'; i.amount` should return 1000

Comment: It returns 1, when I do `i = YourClass.new; i.amount = '1,000'; i.amount`